# Git checkout does not download branch new files

Tags: git, repository, branch, gitlab

I have a problem with a git branch, I'm trying to switch on a different branch where there is some changed files and changed directories but I cannot see these changes on my local repository.

On the master I have:

```
dir1 / files

dir2 / files
```

on the branch I have

```
new_dir1 / files

dir2 / files

dir3 / files
```

When the command `git fetch && git checkout myBranch` I can see on the terminal

```
Checking out files: 100% (31012/31012), done.
Switched to branch 'featured_phase3'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/myBranch'.
```

But the dir1 is not renamed to new_dir1 and the dir3 is not downloaded.

Sure I'm missing something because I'm new to git

Any help will be appreciate

Thxs

Comment: There is some kind of terminology misuse here, because `git checkout` does not "download" *anything*. The `git fetch` command does, but `git fetch` also (quite deliberately) does not affect any of *your* branches, and `git checkout` generally checks out one of your branches. Hence the full process for "download, affect my branch(es), and check them out" requires using `git fetch` followed by some additional command(s) other than *just* `git checkout`. (There are some exceptions because `git checkout` can do other things, but I'm working from your example here.)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/2402383). In short, you need to checkout your branch and then do a `git pull`

Comment: Hi zabeltech thanks but  I've checkout the branch with the git fetch && git checkout myBranch, when I pull the terminal say Already up-to-date.

Comment: shows new_dir1 up if you do ``` git ls-tree -r myBranch --name-only```?

Comment: No, it seems that there are no changes, but in gitlab I can see that directories

Comment: "but in gitlab I can see that directories", make sure your local and remote (gitlab branch) are same!